# How to change GtkWidget background in GTK3?

Tags: application-development, python, gtk3

I'm trying to use [override_background_color](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.4/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-override-background-color) on some GTK3 widgets but they still showing up with the default background color.

Comment: Can you post the code that you used in the end?

Comment: I"ve dropped it because I didn't have the time. Will try it later.

Comment: I managed to do it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381401/set-the-hover-background-color-of-a-gtk3-menuitem) by using CSS in the GTK3 widget.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## GTK+ 1.2

```
  GtkRcStyle *rc_style;
  GdkColor color;

  color.red = 65535;
  color.green = 0;
  color.blue = 0;

  rc_style = gtk_rc_style_new();

  rc_style->bg[GTK_STATE_NORMAL] = color;

  rc_style->color_flags[GTK_STATE_NORMAL] |= GTK_RC_BG;

  gtk_widget_modify_style (widget, rc_style);

  gtk_rc_style_unref (rc_style);
```

## GTK+ 2.24

Using [the GDK Library](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/):

```
GtkWidget *widget; //your widget

  GdkColor color; 

  gdk_color_parse ("red", &color); //setting a color - you can also use RGB

  gtk_widget_modify_bg(widget, GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color); //modifying the background color of the widget
```

Full reference about GdkColor can be found at [GNOME'S Dev Documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Colors.html).

## GTK 3.0

For gtk+3 you can use gtk_css_provider() .Full tutorials and examples can be found at the [GTK+ Forums](http://www.gtkforums.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=988&p=72089&hilit=background+color#p72089).

Comment: I've tried it first but in python there was no `gdk.color_parse()` function IIRC. Let me re-check...

Comment: i am not familiar with pygtk but you can take a look here http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gdkcolor.html

Comment: besides: `Warning

gtk_widget_modify_bg has been deprecated since version 3.0 and should not be used in newly-written code. Use gtk_widget_override_background_color() instead`

Comment: im still using GTK+ 2.24.Can you edit your post with the code which you use to change the background color?that would help

Comment: additionally, what is the widget you are trying to modify?

Comment: I edited my answer with more information.

Comment: adding the code...

Comment: In python you can do something like: `[your widget].override_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL,Gdk.RGBA(1.0,0.0,0.0,1))` or `[your widget].modify_bg(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL,Gdk.color_parse("red"))`

Comment: gtk 3 forum link is broken